# how can implement value getter by Expression.Lambda<Func<T,propertyInfo.DeclaringType>>

Tags: c#

#### code:

```
static Func<T,object> CompileGetValueExpression<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
    var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
    var convert = Expression.TypeAs(property, typeof(object));
    var lambda =Expression.Lambda<Func<T,object>>(convert, instance);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

#### e.g

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new Test{prop1 = 1,prop2="test"};
    var type = data.GetType();
    var props = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var function = CompileGetValueExpression<Test>(prop);
        var result = function(data);
        Console.WriteLine(result);      
    }
}

class Test{
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

this expression function exactly equal to below methods

```
object GetterFunction(Test i) => i.prop1 as object; 
object GetterFunction(Test i) => i.prop2 as object;
```

but i check the IL , the system use boxing to convert class to object class and unboxing when use to confirm the class,it will slow down the efficiency a little bit when used in large quantities.

```
GetterFunction:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.get_prop1
IL_0006:  box         System.Int32
IL_000B:  ret
```

so I want to solve this problem,but I can't put System.Type in generics.
below code is my expected logic:

```
static Func<T,propertyInfo.DeclaringType> CompileGetValueExpression<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    //..
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,propertyInfo.DeclaringType>>(convert, instance).Compile();
}

//after compile
int GetterFunction(Test i) => i.prop1; 
string GetterFunction(Test i) => i.prop2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return arbitrary value types of arbitrary sizes from a method without statically knowing the types ahead of time, you're probably not going to get around boxing them. If the compiler doesn't know what type a value is going to be, then it can't reserve space for it on the stack, can't call its methods without a method table header, and so on, so it needs to go into a temporary reference type-style "box" on the heap.

You can avoid boxing by generating a `Func<Test,int>` if you add another generic 
parameter to `CompileGetValueExpression()`, but that requires you to statically know the type of the property ahead of time so you can call `CompileGetValueExpression<Test,int>()`, you can't loop through arbitrarily typed properties as you do in your example code.

```
// based on the code from your previous question
static Func<T,TProp> CompileGetValueExpression<T, TProp>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{    
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
    var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
    var convert = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(TProp));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,TProp>>(convert, instance).Compile();
}
```

You can also generate the delegate without statically knowing the types, but then you still need to cast the `Delegate` to the specific `Func<Test,int>` before you can call it (at least without `DynamicInvoke` which would incur boxing again).

```
static Delegate CompileGetValueExpression(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{     
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
    var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
    return Expression.Lambda(delegateType, property, instance).Compile();
}
```

Depending on what your actual use case is for this code, you might be able to incorporate the code that is processing the returned property values inside the dynamically generated methods. Just for example, if you always only call `Console.WriteLine` for each value, you could add a `ToString()` call in the generated lambda and always produce a `Func<T, string>`. Then the `int` wouldn't have to be boxed before formatting it as a string. If you're always sending them to a `BinaryWriter`, you call the right `Write(x)` overload inside the lambda, etc.

Comment: ToString and Expression.Lambda(delegateType, property, instance).Compile() .They are great way to do it ! Thanks!